# Symfony 2, createFormBuilder with ChoiceType on Entity, choice_label is int

Tags: php, forms, symfony, formbuilder

I have a little problem with Symfony 2 and the form builder.
I want to create a ChoiceType field based on Doctrine findAll result.

My choices are entities array, but on the choice_label function, the first variable is int !

I put a little code for explain :

```
    $categories = $categoryRepository->findAll();

    foreach ($categories as $value) {
        echo "category name : ".$value->getName()."<br/>";
    }
    /* Result :
        category name : First
        category name : Second
     */        

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($dance)
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nom de la dance'))
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array('label' => 'Description'))
            ->add('creationDate', DateTimeType::class, array('label' => 'Date de création'))
            ->add('category', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $categories,
                'choice_label' => function($category, $key, $index) {
                    var_dump($category);
                    // Result : int(0) 
                    return $category->getName();
                    // Exception !
                },
                'choice_attr' => function($category, $key, $index) {
                    return ['class' => $category->getId()];
                },
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Sauvegarder'))
            ->getForm();
```

Of course, I have a Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on integer ...

Someone can help me on this problem ?

Thank you !

Comment: I you make sure that `$categories` is an array of objects when it's passed to `choices` option? If you comments the `'choice_label'` option then you error pass to `'choice_attr'` option or this works fine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an older version than Symfony 2.7, you can not simply pass an array of objects to the `choices` option. This is only supported in Symfony >=2.7. If you want to do this in Symfony 2.7 or 2.8, you have to activate the [`choices_as_values` option](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/choice.html#example-usage):

```
'choices_as_values' => true
```

By default, in Symfony 2.x `choices` is built the other way around: [the keys of the array become the value and the value of they array becomes the label](http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/reference/forms/types/choice.html#example-usage). So, you'll get 0 for the first element in your array. :)

Alternatively, you may want to use the [`EntityType` class](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/entity.html) instead of `ChoiceType`. It will pass the actual object to the function in any case.

Furthermore, if you want to specify a property of your entity (or a referenced entity) as your label, you can also use [property paths](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label):

```
'choice_label' => 'name'
```

Comment: Thank you, the choices_as_values solved my problem !